# Probleme with portable class and MathNET spatial

Tags: portable-class-library, math.net, mathnet-numerics

I try to install **Math.NET Spatial** in a portable class library in *Visual Studio 2013* but I get an error.
I get this following error in the NuGet Console :

> Install failed. Rolling back... Install-Package : Could not install
>   package 'MathNet.Spatial 0.2.0-alpha'. You  are trying to install this
>   package into a project that targets 'portable-net45+ win+wpa81+wp80',
>   but the package does not contain any assembly references or content
>   files that are compatible with that framework. For more information,
>   cont act the package author. At line:1 char:16
>   + Install-Package <<<<  MathNet.Spatial -Pre
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOper     ationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.C
>   ommands.InstallPackageCommand

It only works when I use a none portable class library on frame work 4.0 but it should work as indicate on the website : http://spatial.mathdotnet.com/

> MathNet.Spatial - core package, including .Net 4, .Net 3.5 and
>   portable/PCL builds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it is indeed planned to support PCL once we reach a full release/1.0, the current prerelease builds are actually built for .Net 4.0 only and do not yet support portable projects.

I've dropped the misleading sentence from the website.

Comment: Thank's for the answer.

Comment: What about support for .Net 3.5?
I tried building from source with > build.cmd Build net35
but it seems to be only building for .Net 4.0.
Is there a way to get a .Net 3.5 build?

Comment: .Net 3.5 is not officially supported either by this specific project. Do you need 3.5 support because of Unity or for other reasons?